# How do you access the fields in a WCF RIA generated Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, query-string, wcf-ria-services

How do you access the controls in a WCF RIA generated Silverlight app?

I've got the page being opened with a number of query string variables 
What I'm trying to do is set the values of the controls on the Silverlight control to these values

EDIT: there seem to be three approaches, `InitParams`, `QueryString` and `HtmlPage.Document`

Full details on Brij Mohan [blog post](http://www.dotnetglobe.com/2011/05/passing-parameters-between-silverlight.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that XAP file is the SECOND item that is downloaded from the website, it is not the first page.  Look into the Javascript of the first page, you will see there are a number of parameters that are issued on the command line to execute the Silverlight application.  It is here that you  take the QueryString on the first page, and pass it on to the Silverlight application.  Couple of links for you....

[CodeProject Example - Shows the mechanics, but not a great implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233915/Passing-parameters-between-Silverlight-and-ASP-NET)

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838255%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers ... as you may have guessed, this is a completely new area that has been dropped on me

Comment: And the article has this link to [Integrating Silverlight with a Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838145(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: Consider yourself lucky - understanding XAML will give you a serious leg up in the next couple of years!

Answer (score 0):

Binding in Silverlight/WPF/XAML is your friend :-). The TwoWay binding mode will not only get the values to the control, but back to the WCF RIA generated objects.

MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) was created to help in just that. I'm not sure how much you know about Silverlight, but personally I wouldn't want to develop in XAML without it. There are lots of tutorials on the web. Here is one I found that should help you: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/MVVM-Sample-for-WCF-RIA-115b1f38